# Rename header file based if names are included in rows of another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, mapping

I would like to rename the header of a file with the names provided from another files. This one stands for the mappings between the names that might be included in the header and the desired names:

For instance here are columns of (`aggregate.csv`) that need to be changed:

```
TEXT,# 1 - A, # 12 - B,# 13 - C,# 3 - D
a,         1,        1,       1,      2
b,         1,        1,       1,      2
c,         1,        1,       1,      2
d,         1,        1,       1,      2
```

and the another file `mapping.csv` that maps between the names of the files and the desired names

```
old,new
A,A
B,A
C,A
D,D
E,D
F,D
G,G
H,G
I,G
```

As one can see the names in the header won't exactly match the `old` column but might rather be included. Indeed, they all have a `# number - NAME` pattern before in `aggregate.csv` file whereas they only have `NAME` in the `mapping.csv`.

For the moment I tried :

```
file = 'mapping.csv'
dictionary = pd.read_csv(file)

header_map = dictionary.set_index("old").to_dict()["new"]

df = pd.read_csv("aggregate.csv")
df = df.rename(columns in header_map)
```

As the columns are not exactly the same, how can I add when there are the same names in the dictionary.

Until now it had a function that worked quite well:

```
def rename_columns(self,df, dictionary):                                
    """
    Rename the columns with the given dictionary

    Maybe we don't need the header map file. 
    Probably it doesn't work on every dataframe depending on the csv file header

    Args:
        df: the dataframe to crunch
        dictionary: the former names mapped with the new ones.

    Returns:
        df_sum: The dataframe with the weird column names renamed        
    """
    print("rename_columns")
    dictionary = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),dictionary))
    header_map = dictionary.set_index("old").to_dict()["new"]
    # Renombra eliminando el patron '#X - '
    df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'#[0-9]* - (.*)',r'\1',x))
    # Usa el archivo de mapeo para renombrar
    df = df.rename(columns = header_map)

    df_sum = df.T.reset_index().groupby("index").sum().T 
    return df_sum
```

But with the next csv :

```
 Map Level, Precinct ID, Precinct Name,#1 - Christian-Democratic Movement,#1 - Georgian Dream,#1 - Giorgi Margvelashvili,#1 - Mikheil Saakashvili,#1 - United National Movement,#10 - Georgian Group,#10 - Giorgi Liluashvili,#10 - Self-governance to People,#10 - Traditionalists - Our Georgia and Women's Party,#10 - United Democratic Movement,#11 - Greens Party,#11 - Nugzar Avaliani,#11 - People's Party,#11 - Sportsman's Union,#12 - Future Georgia,#12 - Levan Chachua,#12 - National Party of Radical Democrats of Georgia,#13 - Akaki Asatiani,#13 - Freedom Party,#13 - Giorgi Chikhladze,#13 - Merab Kostava Society,#13 - Teimuraz Mzhavia,#15 - Public Movement,#16 - Labour Council of Georgia,#16 - Mamuka Melikishvili,#17 - Nestan Kirtadze,#18 - Avtandil Margiani,#18 - Kartlos Gharibashvili,#18 - Tamaz Bibiluri,#2 - Christian-Democratic Movement,#2 - Georgian Group,#2 - Levan Gachechiladze,#2 - Nino Burjanadze,#2 - Republican party,#2 - United National Movement,#21 - Mikheil Saluashvili,#22 - Mamuka Chokhonelidze,#23 - Teimuraz Bobokhidze,#3 - Alliance of Patriots,#3 - Arkadi (Badri) Patarkatsishvili,#3 - Christian-Democratic Movement,#3 - Davit Bakradze,#3 - European Georgia,#3 - National Council,#3 - United Communist Party,#3 - United Opposition,#3 - We Ourselves,#4 - Alliance for Georgia,#4 - Alliance of Patriots,#4 - European Georgia,#4 - Labour,#4 - New Rights,#4 - Republican party,#4 - Shalva Natelashvili,#4 - Traditionalists - Our Georgia and Women's Party,#4 - United Communist Party,#5 - Davit Gamkrelidze,#5 - Democratic Movement - Free Georgia,#5 - Free Georgia,#5 - Giorgi Targamadze,#5 - Industry Will Save Georgia,#5 - Labour,#5 - New Rights,#5 - Right Wing Alliance Topadze Industrialists,#6 - Christian Democratic Alliance,#6 - Christian-Democratic Movement,#6 - Free Georgia,#6 - Georgian Group,#6 - Georgian Politics,#6 - Giorgi (Gia) Maisashvili,#6 - Koba Davitashvili,#6 - Labour,#6 - Movement for Fair Georgia,#6 - National Party of Radical Democrats of Georgia,#6 - Our Country,#6 - Sportsman's Union,#6 - Tortladze Democratic Party,#6 - Unity Hall,#7 - Christian Democratic Alliance,#7 - Future Georgia,#7 - Irina Sarishvili-Chanturia,#7 - Labour,#7 - Movement for Fair Georgia,#7 - National Forum,#7 - Non-Parliamentary Opposition,#7 - Sergo Javakhidze,#8 - Freedom Party,#8 - Georgian Group,#8 - Labour Council of Georgia,#8 - Merab Kostava Society,#8 - National Democratic Party of Georgia,#8 - New Rights,#8 - Nino Chanishvili,#8 - People's Party,#8 - Public Movement,#8 - Right Wing Alliance Topadze Industrialists,#8 - Sportsman's Union,#8 - United Communist Party,#8 - Way of Georgia,#9 - Armed Veterans Patriots,#9 - Freedom Party,#9 - Our Country,#9 - Sportsman's Union,#9 - Zurab Kharatishvili,Armed Veterans Patriots,Average votes per minute (08:00-12:00),Average votes per minute (12:00-15:00),Average votes per minute (12:00-17:00),Average votes per minute (15:00-20:00),Average votes per minute (17:00-20:00),Christian Democrats,Election,For United Georgia,Freedom Party,Future Georgia,Georgia,Georgian Party,Georgian Unity and Development Party,Greens Party,In the Name of the Lord,Initiative Group,Invalid Ballots (%),Labour,Labour Council of Georgia,Leftist Alliance,Lord Our Righteousness,Mamulishvili,Merab Kostava Society,More Ballots Than Votes (#),More Votes Than Ballots (#),National Democratic Party of Georgia,National Forum,National Party of Radical Democrats of Georgia,New Christian Democrats,New Rights,Nikoloz Ivanishvili Public Democrats,Our Country,Our Georgia,Overall Results,Party of Future,Party of People,People's Movement,People's Party,Progressive Democratic Movement,Public Alliance of Whole Georgia,Reformers,Republican party,Self-governance to People,Socialist Workers Party,Solidarity,Sportsman's Union,State for the People,Total Voter Turnout (#),Total Voter Turnout (%),Union of Georgian Traditionalists,United Communist Party,Unity - New Georgia,Way of Georgia
Precinct,1,83-1,51.28,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,30.77,,,,,,,,,,,,,,17.95,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2008 Adjara Supreme Council - Majoritarian Re-run,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Christian-Democratic Movement,,,,,,,,,,,,,,39,4.5,,,,
...
```

And it returns:

```
we are cleaning file : C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Richmond\data/raw/aggregated\Khelvachauri-aggregated.csv
rename_colummns
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1505, in na_op
    result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 208, in evaluate
    return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 123, in _evaluate_numexpr
    result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 68, in _evaluate_standard
    return op(a, b)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1529, in safe_na_op
    return na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1507, in na_op
    result = masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1009, in masked_arith_op
    com.values_from_object(yrav[mask]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Richmond\scrapper.py", line 232, in clean_directory
    self.clean_csv(df, fname)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Richmond\scrapper.py", line 251, in clean_csv
    df = self.merge_sum_similar(df)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Richmond\scrapper.py", line 349, in merge_sum_similar
    df_sum['New Right'] = df_sum['New Rights'] + df_sum['New Right']
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1583, in wrapper
    result = safe_na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1533, in safe_na_op
    lambda x: op(x, rvalues))
  File "pandas/_libs/algos.pyx", line 690, in pandas._libs.algos.arrmap
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1533, in <lambda>
    lambda x: op(x, rvalues))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Can you simplify the example to perhaps 2 column replacements? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `df.iloc` returns a value, it's not like `C` where you can return a reference to a memory location and assign to it.

Comment: @PeterWood Sure, is it better now ?

Comment: The input data could be reduced. Where you say "the columns are not exactly the same", describe the differences and the difficulty matching them.

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, I changed and reduced it. The name in the colums of `aggregate.csv` are not exactly the same with mapping as far as they all have a `# number - NAME` pattern in `aggregate.csv` file whereas they only have `NAME` in the `mapping.csv`